# How to guarantee two conditions in a return type

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I would like to have a method whose return type inherits from a specific type AND implements a specific interface.

That is to say that the following method `TReturn? GetData();` can return object from the following two classes, such that I can handle the returned object either as a TBase object or an IExpected one.

```
class1 : TBase, IExpected
class2 : TBase, IExpected
```

NB : a possible solution is to have a common class that do nothing :

```
Class12Base : TBase, IExpected
class1 : Class12Base 
class2 : Class12Base 

Class12Base  GetData();
```

..but I can't modify class 1 nor 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid. You can document it and be careful in the implementation, and just pick *one* of the relevant types to act as the return type, but that's all there is :(

(I'm assuming you don't want to make the method generic in its return type and constrain that type parameter... that would put the burden onto the *caller* to specify the type...)